# Ruby Code Kata: LocalJumpError: yield called out of block

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to work on a simple ruby kata. I don't really know the concept of yield so I don't really understand what this error means:

```
LocalJumpError: yield called out of block
```

Essentially I'm just trying to make this these test cases pass with this code:

```
def compute
  return yield
 "Do not compute"
end

Test.expect(compute { "Block" }, "Block")
Test.expect(compute, "Do not compute")
```

The first test case passes but the second doesn't. Shouldn't it pass though. The return yield should stop the function early with the block. If the method call does not have  a block then it should go straight towards "Do not compute" Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`block_given?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F)

```
def compute
  return yield if block_given?
  "Do not compute"
end
```

`yield` always expects a block to yield to, so you have to prevent the yield from occurring yourself if you don't have a block. Thankfully, there's the inbuilt method, `block_given?` that can tell you whether there's been a block provided or not.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That block_given? is pretty handy. Never knew that existed.

Comment: That was useful to me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the return statement.

Once you call return, you exits the method, so the "Do not compute" statement is never reached.